# Finding the right PGP key for decryption

Tags: pgp

I have around 50 secret Keys on my Old Server and I have been running script to decrypt the file

c:\gnupg\gpg.exe --passphrase-fd 0 --decrypt --quiet --batch --output "xx.txt" "xx.txt.pgp"
I want to start doing this on another server, so I would need to export the private Key to the new Server. Question is that when I run the above command on my old server, it decrypts the file using a private key in those 50 keys, I want to know which private key is that one. How to do this

so I can get the list

c:\gnupg\gpg.exe --list-secret-keys
and I can import the Key from there, but I want to find out which key to export. Any help

Answer (score 0):

Use `--list-packets`:

```
 gpg.exe --list-packets file.gpg
```

Result:

```
 gpg: encrypted with 3072-bit RSA key, ID 1234567890ABCDEF, created 2021-06-17
  "john <john.smith@example.domain>"
```

With that e-mail or its ID you may then get the correct key:

```
 gpg.exe --list-key 1234567890ABCDEF
 gpg.exe --list-key john.smith@example.domain
```

The above example does not decrypt, but rather only shows information on how it was encrypted.